# How to make fragment opening modally have partially transparent background?

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I am trying to get it so that a fragment I open modally has a semi-opaque background. I can do it by setting the opacity of the stage, but I can't actually use that method because it then makes all the text and buttons I have in the modal window semi-opaque as well. Is there a way to set the *background* of the stage to be transparent? Or set it to a color with a low alpha value and then have the root of the fragment be transparent? Here is a test I whipped up to show the issue.

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
import javafx.stage.StageStyle
import tornadofx.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<ModalTransparencyTest>(args)
}

class ModalTransparencyTest: App(TestView::class)

class TestView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        alignment = Pos.CENTER
        button("open modal window").action {
            val newStage = TestFragment().openModal(StageStyle.UTILITY, escapeClosesWindow = true)
            if (newStage != null) {
                newStage.scene.fill = Color.TRANSPARENT
                //don't want to set stage's opacity as that will set
                //all of the stage's children to be less opqaue as well
                //just want to set the stage's background to be semi-transparent
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDock() {
        super.onDock()
        primaryStage.width = 800.0
        primaryStage.height = 600.0
    }
}

class TestFragment: Fragment() {
    override val root = vbox {
        text("I am a test fragment")

        style {
            backgroundColor += c(.2, .2, .2, .8)
        }

        prefWidth = 300.0
        prefHeight = 200.0
    }
}
```

As you can see the background of the fragment is not turning transparent as expected. Am I doing this incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [`StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#TRANSPARENT)?

Comment: This just removes the styling from around the border of the stage which makes it not have a top bar with x, - , etc.

Comment: It also makes the background of the window transparent allowing you to set the scene's/root's/other nodes' background to transparent/semi-transparent and see through the window. Currently you're (probably, assuming no nodes are getting in the way) seeing the window decorations (provided by the OS) "behind" the transparent `Scene`. But it does remove the title bar, resizing functionality, and some animations (minimize/maximize). Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, JavaFX provides no functionality to keep the title bar but have the rest of the window's decorations be transparent.

Comment: That is unfortunate indeed. I guess I can try to re-create the functionality of a decorated window with the Transparent style enabled. I swear I tried this before and it wasn't working, but switching it to `Styles.TRANSPARENT` did indeed make it transparent. I'll try to get this working somehow. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer I will accept it!